# How to disable after_validation method in all tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to get to grips with testing in Rails.

In one of my models I have `after_validation :grab_external_stuff`. `grab_external_stuff` is a method that calls an external API. I don't want to run this in my tests.

What is the correct way to disable this `after_validation` method in my tests? How do I do it (using rspec)? And where do I do it?

I know that stub can be used to stop a method being called. But I'm struggling to see how to apply it to after_validation or similar hooks.

For example, say I have a task, that belongs to a project, that belongs to a user. I run a factory(:task), which is also creating associated project and user. But when the user is validated, grab_external_stuff gets called.

So where in my tests should I be specifying that I don't want to run this method? In the tests, in the factories, somewhere else?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `grab_external_stuff` actually a method? Perhaps defined in a module or as a class method in one of your models? If that's the case, and you're certain you never want it to run, you can stub it out like you said:

```
before(:suite) do
    Model.any_instance.stub(:grab_external_stuff) { nil } # if it's an instance method
    # or:
    # Model.stub(:grab_external_stuff) { nil } if it's a class method, etc
end
```

You can set that up in your spec_helper, or per test, etc.

The fact that this method is being called by an after_validation block is irrelevant, because it's just a method and can be stubbed like any other.

**EDIT** Even if this validation is being done because you're making something in a Factory, it will still be stubbed out. You will create from the Factory in a test, but the `before` will be either `before(:suite)`, `:all`, or `:each`, but regardless, it will run and call the stubbing before the `it {}` is even encountered, thus before your Factory is ever called, meaning that it will *always* be stubbed.

Comment: thanks MrDanA, that makes sense. But what if I want to have more fine grained control? If my test runs Factory(:task), which also creates associated records, how would I stub out methods in the associated models? `:grab_external_stuff` is a class method.

Comment: Thanks! I think I was looking at this the wrong way round. I was trying to pass the stub dynamically, something like `Factory(:task, stubs: User.stub(:grab_external_stuff))` (I've no idea what the syntax would have looked like, but you get the idea!). Is there ever a case where you would do something like this. Or is this totally the wrong track? (Thanks, stil trying to get to grips with testing!!)

Comment: I don't believe that the Factory takes in stubs like that, but I'm not 100% certain of that. I think doing the stub before everything is best though, because then you can forget it and just start making your task objects and not have to worry about whether or not you stubbed - because you did!

Answer (score 1):

You could stub the `:grab_external_stuff` method as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10707614/17410). Another approach is to stub the API request using [FakeWeb](https://rubygems.org/gems/fakeweb). This is probably better for integration tests -- stubbing `:grab_external_stuff` is more appropriate for a unit test IMO.

Comment: thanks zetetic, thats really useful info. At the moment I'm building unit tests, but will be shifting focus to integration tests very soon. Your link to Fakeweb will be useful. Thanks